# Can a Harlequin ZX Spectrum clone be modifed to run CP/M?

Tags: floppy-disk, zx-spectrum, cp-m, zx-spectrum-clones

The ZX Spectrum (and therefore the [Harlequin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZX_Spectrum_clones#Harlequin)) has its ROM from `$0000` to `$3FFF`, while RAM further up to `$5AFF` is used for the screen (see [Memory-Map](http://www.breakintoprogram.co.uk/computers/zx-spectrum/memory-map)). As CP/M expects RAM from `$0000` upwards the two are incompatable by default, but CP/M is available  for the ZX Spectrum +3.

How might it be possible to easily modify a Harlequin to add RAM paging so CP/M could run?

Maybe with a [Beta 128 disk interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Disk_Interface)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the "Superfo Harlequin 128 (issue 4)" supports ALLRAM mode

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=E0ADBB58ADB8D869%21209864&cid=E0ADBB58ADB8D869

You can connect a floppy disk interface and run CP/M 2.2 or CP/M Plus, the same as a ZX Spectrum +3

Comment: Mind to turn this into a full answer, otherwise it's at best a link only comment to [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8563/6659). If not an (even less well received) advertisement?

Answer (score 10):

well even old **ZX 48K** and clones have exposed the **AD/DB/CB** buses along with `/ROMCS` signal which can actively disable inbuild **ROM**. So you can make a small HW that has 16 KByte of **SRAM** that replaces the ROM with a jumper or switch or programaticaly using some flip/flop and address decoder.

This technique is used by any HW peripherial with its own **ROM** for example like this:

- [D40/D80 FDC+FDD](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didaktik_40)

  [image: D40 image]

Developing such HW should be quite easy for anyone with the EE knowledge as its really just a connection between BUSes and the IC. I would also add some LED indicating the state of `/ROMCS`

However I think there should be some HW peripherial capable of this already out there so just look may be some **DivIDE** or MMC card interface for ZX ...

I am not familiar with **CP/M** (other than that it requires 64 KByte of RAM in full AB range which actively mess up running its stuff on ZX and need some porting) but I think it would need some tweaking or adding driver for the display as there is not much options to move the SCREEN file from its location.

For example here schematic for D40 taken from [mts.speccy.cz](https://mts.speccy.cz/doc_zxs.htm)

[image: D40 MDOS 1.0]

The IC11 (27128) is the EPROM mapped instead of ZX original ROM The `CE` chip enable signal is connected to the adress decoder (that is active in address range `<0-16383>`)  The `/RD` is connected to **Z80 CPU** `/RD` and you woul dneed just replace **EPROM** with **SRAM** and also connect the `/WR` signal.

The only thing left to see in the circuit is the `/ROMCS`  on the image is called `ROMOFF` on the image its the open collector of transistor T1 just above the EPROM (the text is not recognizable but I am confirming this with my own paper version of the circuit)

so in the nutshell I see it like this:

[image: full RAM mode]

Where **jp1** will switch between FULL RAM mode and normal ZX ROM operation. If you want to switch programatically then remove the jumper and add a flip flop + I/O space address decoder instead of it.

I assume you want to load some stuff like OS into some memory first (using in build ZX ROM), than switch to FULL RAM and move the OS to desired locations and run it. So you would also need to write a small probably assembly loader that do this for you.

**[Edit 1] I just found this:**

- [CP/M 2.2 on ZX spectrum](https://cs.speccy.cz/programs/CPM_v2.2.zip)

Which looks like contain ROM file,CP/M 2.2 TZX file and PDF with description and Schematics for the RAM extention which more or less covers this answer fully.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe something like the pagable ROM module from the RC2014 could be used

Comment: @PaulHumphreys yes the [design](http://rc2014.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Paged-ROM.pdf)  is almost what you need ... you just need to switch the (E/E/P/)ROM with SRAM and also add `/WR` signal connection. But as you cas see its just connector + ROM/RAM + address decoder + flip/flop/latch for activation. However the variable page size a bit complicates the decoder ... What you need could be a bit easier

Comment: @PaulHumphreys just to be sure I added edit to my answer with some circuitry ...

Comment: Even if you paged RAM into the bottom 16k, a 48k Spectrum wouldn't be suitable for CP/M because of the video RAM at 0x4000. On a 128 things are better because the second screen in bank 7 can be used, and paged in and out as required.

Comment: @john_e I was afraid of that (and mention exactly this same in the answer just above the circuitry of the D40/D80) ... however I saw programs ported from CP/M to ZX like ZEXALL and they works ... maybe adding some driver would enable the ZX48k for CP/M too (like allocate the SCREEN FILE location to prevent OS to use it) but still this approach should be usable even for 128K and later models

Comment: @PaulHumphreys check this [ZXCP-M2.2.dsk.zip](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=0023486) out IIRC Beta is a FDC for ZX128K  I am not familiar with it as I am used to MDOS D40/D80 which are very common in my area (as they where developed and produced here)

Comment: @PaulHumphreys I added edit1 to my answer ... looks like that is exatly what you need...

Answer (score 8):

The hardware modifications are possible, and actually already done. The ["SuperFoo Harlequin 128"](http://trastero.speccy.org/cosas/JL/Harlequin/superfo1.html) is an all-RAM design based on the original Harlequin that should be capable of running CP/M (Just like the +2 and +3).

I haven't heard of someone actually running CP/M on such a machine, but based on its +3 compatibility, it shouldn't be too hard. Some of the boards based on this design come with a built-in DIVMMC - See my question [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/are-there-any-drivers-available-to-use-divmmc-on-the-spectrum-3e-with-cp-m-plus) (that is unfortunately still missing a definitive answer) related to this and CP/M.

Comment: Doesn't the superfo harlequin only support the 128k memory mapping though? The +3 had a new memory mapping setting just to support CP/M https://www.worldofspectrum.org/faq/reference/128kreference.htm

Comment: @PaulHumphreys The Harlequin 128 with superfoo mods runs the +3 ROM, so I would expect it uses the same (all-RAM) memory layout.

Comment: The zip file containing the 128K mods shows it running the 128k ROM and not the +3 one and the screenshots only show the 128k mode being tested and not the all RAM mode unique to the +3 and some +2s. In addition, the .txt file in the superfo docs says "For 128K, signal 1FFD is not used.". Port 0x1FFD is needed to switch to all RAM mode. I do notice the superfo design uses *2* 128k ram chips. Does the superfo have some other means of switching to all ram perhaps?

Comment: Mine runs the +3 ROM. I have a Chinese re-make (ZX Omni). On second thought, I am, however, not 100% sure if the +3 ROM ever switches into all-RAM mode.

Comment: If you have a 128k harlequin, would you be able to test whether the all ram mode is accessible somehow and report back?

Comment: @PaulHumphreys Sure. Might just take me a bit of time as I first have to think up how to do this ;)